# Sqlcommand AND seems to ignore first parameter

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-c++

When i use AND in my sqlcommand code it only follow the last bit

```
        SqlCommand^ FinArstiCmd = gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ARSTI1 WHERE SLIMID=' 
        @SlimuID ' AND UNIQJOBID=' @JobID ';", con);

        FinArstiCmd->Parameters->Add("@SlimuID", SqlDbType::VarChar);
        FinArstiCmd->Parameters->Add("@JobID", SqlDbType::VarChar);
        FinArstiCmd->Parameters["@SlimuID"]->Value = SlimId1;
        FinArstiCmd->Parameters["@JobID"]->Value = JobID1;


        SqlDataReader^ FinArstRead;

        try {
            con->Open();

            String^ ArstaVards;
            FinArstRead = FinArstiCmd->ExecuteReader();

            while (FinArstRead->Read()){
                ArstaVards = FinArstRead["FULL_NAME"]->ToString();
                listBox1->Items->Add(ArstaVards);

            }
            con->Close();
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
```

when i use code above it outputs every row in the database that only has the correct @jobid, not the ones which have both parameters correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why your seeing rows returned at all, frankly (other than you have entries where SLIMID is literally the value `@SlimuID` and UNIQJOBID is `@JobID`). Is this really, the code you use or some mocked up example?

Anyway don't put the parameters in quotes:

```
    SqlCommand^ FinArstiCmd = gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ARSTI1 WHERE SLIMID=' 
    @SlimuID ' AND UNIQJOBID=' @JobID ';", con);
```

That way the SQL parser thinks you're looking for the actual value `@SlimuID` of the column `SLIMID`.

Correct:

```
    SqlCommand^ FinArstiCmd = gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ARSTI1 WHERE SLIMID= 
    @SlimuID AND UNIQJOBID=@JobID;", con);
```

(Another) good thing about parameterized queries is, that the correct quoting - if required at all, think about INT values, will be handled by the database engine.